# Implementing Arrays in Java Class

Tags: java, object-oriented, array

I have the following code to write:

> Modify the Student class so that instead of 3 tests you will now have
>   an array of 100 tests. However, not all of the scores may be set. You
>   need to add an additional field to keep track of the number of tests
>   currently being stored. You will need to modify setTest and getTest as
>   well. Also, add a method titled addTest that will add a new test score
>   in the appropriate location. This is the code I have to write/modify
>   and this is what I've done with it.

```
package net.apcs.classes;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Student {

    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private double[] Tests = new double[100];
    private int NumberOfTests;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        tests = new double[100];
        NumberOfTests = numberOfTests;
    }

    public Student() {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
        Tests = new double[100];
        NumberOfTests = 0;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() { return LastName; }

    public double getTest(int testNum) {
        return Tests[testNum];
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setTest(int testNum, double testScore, double[] tests) {
        tests[testNum] = testScore;
    }

    public double getAverage(double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        while (i < numberOfTests) {
            sum = sum + tests[i];
            i++;
        }
        double average = sum / numberOfTests;
        return average;
    }

    public double getHighScore(double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
        double max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
            if (tests[i] > max) {
                max = tests[i];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "FirstName='" + FirstName + '\'' +
                ", LastName='" + LastName + '\'' +
                ", " + Arrays.toString(Tests);
    }
}
```

Could somebody look over this to see if I implemented the arrays properly? I'm not sure if I used them properly and if the code will do what it's supposed to. (Before anyone asks, I don't know how to create an object with an array and test the program to see if it works so if someone could tell me how to do that as well, it would be much appreciated).

Comment: You'll have to determine if it works properly.  We cannot review it in case it's broken.  We also cannot assist with adding new implementation (the last statement).

Answer (score 1):

#### Java constructors

You say

> ```
>     private double[] Tests = new double[100];
> ```

but then in the constructor, you say

> ```
>         Tests = new double[100];
> ```

One of those is unnecessary.  You are overwriting the first with the second.  So you could get rid of either one and the code behavior would stay the same.

And in the other other constructor, you say

> ```
>     public Student(String firstName, String lastName, double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
>         FirstName = firstName;
>         LastName = lastName;
>         tests = new double[100];
>         NumberOfTests = numberOfTests;
>     }
> ```

In Java, the standard is to write class names StudlyCase and variable names camelCase.  Here, you write variable names StudlyCase.  It would be more common to write this

```
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int numberOfTests) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        tests = new double[numberOfTests];
    }
```

Notice how I do not pass in an array.  Your original code wrote over but never used that array.  This code sets the field `tests` (the camelCase form of `Tests`) in the object based on the number of tests.  It does not have to save the number of tests, because the array stores that information in Java.  You could also say

```
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, double[] tests) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.tests = tests;
    }
```

This would normally be used to set the test *values* at the time of construction.

> ```
>     public Student() {
>         FirstName = "";
>         LastName = "";
>         Tests = new double[100];
>         NumberOfTests = 0;
>     }
> ```

This seems pointless.  You have no way of changing `NumberOfTests` later.  So why have it?

#### Setters should change the object

> ```
>     public void setTest(int testNum, double testScore, double[] tests) {
>         tests[testNum] = testScore;
>     }
> ```

Why would `setTest` set a value in an array that you pass to it?

#### Lists would make more sense than an array

This particular use case seems better suited to a `List` than an array.  With a list, you could say

```
    public void addTest(double testScore) {
        tests.add(testScore);
    }
```

and it would automatically resize and put the test in the right spot.  That way you wouldn't have to know how many tests there were before adding.

But of course, you may be required to use an array.

#### Iterate with `for` rather than `while`

You say

> ```
>     int i = 0;
>     double sum = 0;
>     while (i < numberOfTests) {
>         sum = sum + tests[i];
>         i++;
>     }
> ```

But you could write this more idiomatically as

```
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        sum += tests[i];
    }
```

and even easier as

```
    double sum = 0;
    for (double test : tests) {
        sum += test;
    }
```

Now you don't have to care about the loop variable.  Java will handle that for you.

Note that I also shortened `sum = sum + test` to just `sum += test`.  Both statements do the same thing, but the latter is shorter.

#### Class vs. object methods

In a method like one of

> ```
>     public void setTest(int testNum, double testScore, double[] tests) {
>     public double getAverage(double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
>     public double getHighScore(double[] tests, int numberOfTests) {
> ```

You would either make these `static` class methods or remove the parameters that already exist in the class.  In this case, the latter seems better

```
    public void setTest(int testNum, double testScore) {
    public double getAverage() {
    public double getHighScore() {
```

Now these methods would be based on just what is in the class.  The caller doesn't have to maintain arrays.  That's why you have classes and objects, so that callers can abstract away from the things defined in the class.

Using an array for storage already puts extra strain on the caller.  The caller needs to know how many tests there are before creating the `Student` object.  Or you need to reinvent `List` functionality using an array.

#### `main`

@Jamal said that we wouldn't write test code for you, but I'm going to give you a bit of a push:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] scores = {100.0, 50.0, 90.0};
        Student test = new Student("Test", "Student", scores);
        System.out.println("Average:  " + test.getAverage());
    }
```

This initializes a student with three test scores and prints out the average score.

It would be better to test with unit tests, but this at least produces some output.  You'll have to write additional tests on your own.  The easy way to use this is to add it as a method for `Student`.  The more robust way would be to add a new class called something like `Main` and put it there.